# Flask template not loading

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask

Good evening. I am trying to stop a user from coming onto my site with reCaptcha v3. However, the template to do this is not loading, despite being called:

```
from flask import url_for, render_template, redirect, request, render_template_string
from flask import current_app as app
from .forms import *
from .filewriter import *
from .mailserver import *
from .rcvalidator import *
from flask_jsglue import JSGlue

jsglue = JSGlue(app)

@app.route('/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def home():
    reqform = ReqForm()
    delform = DelForm()
    error = 0
    if request.method == "POST":
        gtoken = request.json['gtoken']
        if not rc_form_valid(gtoken):
            print("working")
            return redirect(url_for('inv')) #would prefer to have the loaded thing here but as a test tried to lad a different function
    return render_template('home.html',
                           reqform=reqform,
                           delform=delform,
                           csrf_token=0,
                           errors=error)


@app.route('/req', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def req():
    reqform = ReqForm()
    delform = DelForm()
    if reqform.validate_on_submit():
        appendfile("req.csv", reqform)
        mail(reqform.name.data, reqform.tel.data, "recipient")
        return redirect(url_for('success'))
    elif request.method == "POST" and not reqform.validate():
        error = 1 
    else:
        error = 0
    return render_template('home.html',
                           reqform=reqform,
                           delform=delform,
                           csrf_token=reqform.csrf_token,
                           errors = error)


@app.route('/delv', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def delv():
    reqform = ReqForm()
    delform = DelForm()
    if delform.validate_on_submit():
        appendfile("del.csv", delform)
        mail(delform.name.data, delform.tel.data, "delivery")
        return redirect(url_for('success'))
    elif request.method == "POST" and not delform.validate():
        error = 2
    else:
        error = 0
    return render_template('home.html',
                           reqform=reqform,
                           delform=delform,
                           csrf_token=delform.csrf_token,
                           errors = error)


@app.route('/success')
def success():
    return render_template('success.html') 

@app.route('/invalid', methods=(['GET']))
def inv():
    print("loaded inv") 
    return "get out now"

@app.route('/cancel', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def cancel():
    canform = CanForm()
    if canform.validate_on_submit():
        # TODO: delete stuff from form
        return redirect(url_for('success'))
    elif request.method == "POST" and not delform.validate():
        error = 1
    else:
        error = 0
    return render_template('cancel.html',
                           canform=canform,
                           csrf_token=canform.csrf_token,
                           errors=error)
```

"working" and "loaded inv" print, but the new template does not render, and I don't understand why. When I submit a form, success.html renders. Please help

Comment: Do you redirect to 'inv' and routing is '/invalid' not 'inv', typo?

Comment: @SlawomirDziuba No, url_for finds the url that accompanies the function (in this case inv)

Answer (score 0):

A good overall practice is to know what a 'GET' and what a 'POST'will do.

In your code we know what 'POST' does in home() but not what 'GET' does so try this:

```
@app.route('/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def home():
    reqform = ReqForm()
    delform = DelForm()
    error = 0
    if request.method == "POST":
        gtoken = request.json['gtoken']
        if not rc_form_valid(gtoken):
            print("working")
            return redirect(url_for('inv')) 
    elif request.method=='GET':
        return render_template('home.html',
                              reqform=reqform,
                              delform=delform,
                              csrf_token=0,
                              errors=error)
```

Comment: Nah, nothing changed. Still getting the print statement. I think it might be something to do  with loading the home.html and changing links. I can post any more code if neccessary.

Comment: in inv() you need to also return render_template('home.html') If this is the correct comment I will update my answer.
You need it because in home() you are redirecting to url_for('inv') and make sure to check the url when submiting a form

Comment: what do you mean? Doesn't it defeat the purpose to have it redirct to home.html (effectively itself)?

Comment: It depends how you architecture it, but it won`t render a template unless you tell it to do so . Now its only returning "get out now". 
You are basicly redirecting to "get out now"

Comment: yes, I would like to do that. However, when the code is run, nothing happens. The print statements run and the page continues to be home.html

Comment: try to return a render_template or any redirect in inv() 
try to debug and tell us the results

Comment: using render_template_string() doesn't change anything